How can I link assembly code with a C file for the sole purpose of calling C functions in to my assembly code? Linking only runs C code afterwards
I'm doing a project to learn how assembly code integrates into programming languages so I can understand machine code abstraction at depth while working on large projects.
I am using VScode for editing but I'm using MSVC tools with developer command line for compiling each file into a .obj file. My assembly is supposed to print a "Choose a menu option" and then 4 menu items to console upon execution, but it's currently only printing the test string in my C file after I link them.
Compiling main.asm: [ ml /c main.asm ]
Compiling procedures.c: [ cl /c procedures.c ]
Linking files: [ link main.obj procedures.obj /OUT:spectra.exe /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /ENTRY:central /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\lib\x86" ucrt.lib libcmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT ]
main.asm:
.model flat, stdcall

    EXTERN sayHello: PROC

    .data
        ; Menu strings
       menu_msg DB "Select a menu option 1 - 4:$"

    .code
    central PROC near stdcall
        ; Print menu options
        lea dx, menu_msg         ; Load address of menu message
        mov ah, 09h              ; DOS interrupt for printing strings
        int 21h 
    
        call sayHello

    central ENDP

    END

procedures.c:
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>


    /* Testing & Debugging Functions */
    __declspec(dllexport) void sayHello() {
        printf("Hello from C!\n");
    }

I've tried linking them in 10 different ways ranging from specifying the /SUBSYSTEM to /ENTRY to specifying the exact libraries in my MSVC folder and it only executes code I explicitly put in the C file, never runs anything in the assembly file. What can I do make the assembly code execute and print a message to the console?
UPDATE: I was trying to make 16 bit assembly run in the terminal of 64 bit Windows. I have some updated code that I have been able to finally run from terminal after linking, but I haven't been able to print from console specifically. The C file remains the same but my assembly has been updated to open a message box and show the text so far.
Compile Assembly = [ ml64 /c /Fo main2.obj main2.asm ]
Compile C Code = [ cl /c procedures.c /Fo:procedures.obj ]
Link files: [ link /OUT:spectra.exe main2.obj procedures.obj /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /ENTRY:main /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\lib\x64" user32.lib libucrt.lib libvcruntime.lib ]
; main2.asm (for 64-bit)

option casemap:none

EXTERN MessageBoxA: PROC
EXTERN ExitProcess: PROC
EXTERN sayHello: PROC

.data
    menu_msg db "Select a menu option:", 0  ; Title of the message box
    option1 db "1. Add two numbers", 0
    option2 db "2. Subtract two numbers", 0
    option3 db "3. Multiply two numbers", 0
    option4 db "4. Divide two numbers", 0

    ; Combine the menu options in the message body
    combined_msg db "1. Add two numbers", 0, "2. Subtract two numbers", 0
    msg_line2 db "3. Multiply two numbers", 0, "4. Divide two numbers", 0

.code
main PROC
    ; Align the stack to 16-byte boundary
    sub rsp, 8                      ; Adjust stack for 16-byte alignment

    ; Call MessageBoxA with the new title and combined message
    mov rcx, 0                      ; uType (0 = OK button)
    lea rdx, option1                ; lpCaption (title of the message box)
    lea r8, menu_msg                ; lpText (message with menu options)
    mov r9, 0                       ; hWnd (no parent window)
    call MessageBoxA                ; Call MessageBoxA API

    ; Add another message box with second part if needed
    lea r8, msg_line2               ; Update text to the next part
    call MessageBoxA                ; Call MessageBoxA API again

    ; Call sayHello procedure (assuming sayHello is implemented in C)
    call sayHello

    ; Exit the program
    mov rcx, 0                      ; Exit code (0)
    call ExitProcess                ; Call ExitProcess API

    ; Clean up the stack
    add rsp, 8                      ; Restore stack

main ENDP

END


I've never used this toolchain for asm development, but to me this looks like a mixture of Windows and DOS code. Does MSVC 14 even support DOS programs?

Your problem is not the linking. Your problem is that you tried to use code intended for DOS.

@Jester Oh I see. I was trying to make 16 bit assembly run in the terminal of 64 bit Windows. I have some updated code that I have been able to finally run from terminal after linking, but I haven't been able to print from console specifically.

x64 Windows can't run 16-bit DOS programs, unless that's changed recently.  It would need to emulate or use Hyper-V to fully virtualize since VM86 mode isn't supported by the ISA in long mode (under a 64-bit kernel).  You'd need to run inside an emulator like DOSBox or Bochs.  So probably if you were building a console application that was able to run, it was a normal native Windows 32 or 64-bit application.  Especially if you built it with modern MSVC, which definitely doesn't support creating 16-bit executables.

The asm you posted in your edit is 64-bit code, not 16-bit.  Do you actually want to write obsolete/retrocomputing 16-bit code, or do you just want to write an assembly program that runs in a text console?  Those are two very different things.

@PeterCordes No you're right, I just need an assembly program to run on windows x64 with a linked C file to outsource the more complex functions like algebra and creating custom message boxes etc.

Ok, then there's your problem.  Write 64-bit code, and don't use any int instructions.  int 21h is DOS, other int numbers are mostly BIOS.  int 80h is Linux's 32-bit system-call interface, which you don't want to use either in 64-bit code even on Linux.  You also don't want to use syscall; Windows doesn't have a stable/documented syscall ABI; call through the DLLs instead.  So if you see examples showing int or syscall, they're not for x64 Windows (or they're about low-level fun stuff like reverse-engineering the syscall ABI the DLLs use), look for a different tutorial.

@PeterCordes Okay thank you for the help. I'll mark this as solved.

The way to do that is to post a self-answer. Or flag it as a duplicate of an existing question if there is one, now that you know what to look for.

Solved by @PeterCordes: "Ok, then there's your problem. Write 64-bit code, and don't use any int instructions. int 21h is DOS, other int numbers are mostly BIOS. int 80h is Linux's 32-bit system-call interface, which you don't want to use either in 64-bit code even on Linux. You also don't want to use syscall; Windows doesn't have a stable/documented syscall ABI; call through the DLLs instead. So if you see examples showing int or syscall, they're not for x64 Windows (or they're about low-level fun stuff like reverse-engineering the syscall ABI the DLLs use), look for a different tutorial."
